# I want to improve speed of my algorithm with multiple rows input. Python. Find average of consequitive elements in list

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I need to find average of consecutive elements from list.
At first I am given lenght of list,

then list with numbers,

then am given how many test i need to perform(several rows with inputs),

then I am given several inputs to perform tests(and need to print as many rows with results)

every row for test consist of start and end element in list.

```
My algorithm:
nu = int(input())              # At first I am given lenght of list
numbers = input().split()      # then list with numbers
num = input()                  # number of rows with inputs
k =[float(i) for i in numbers] # given that numbers in list are of float type
i= 0
while i < int(num):
 a,b = input().split()          # start and end element in list
 i += 1
 print(round(sum(k[int(a):(int(b)+1)])/(-int(a)+int(b)+1),6)) # round up to 6 decimals
```

But it's not fast enough.I was told it;s better to get rid of "while" but I don't know how. Appreciate any help.

```
Example:
Input:
8 - len(list)
79.02 36.68 79.83 76.00 95.48 48.84 49.95 91.91 - list
10 - number of test
0 0 - a1,b1
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
0 6
0 7
1 7
2 7
Output:
79.020000
57.850000
65.176667
67.882500
73.402000
69.308333
66.542857
69.713750
68.384286
73.668333
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i= 0
while i < int(num):
     a,b = input().split()          # start and end element in list
     i += 1
```

Replace your while-loop with a for loop. Also you could get rid of multiple int calls in the print statement:

```
for _ in range(int(num)):
    a, b = [int(j) for j in input().split()]
```

Comment: Still not fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't spell out the constraints, but I am guessing that the ranges to be averaged could be quite large. Computing `sum(k[int(a):(int(b)+1)])` may take a while.

However, if you precompute partial sums of the input list, each query can be answered in a constant time (sum of numbers in the range is a difference of corresponding partial sums).